# Implementing Lz-string 1.4.4 library to using CompressTOUTF16 Function angular7?

Tags: angular

I used lz-string 1.4.4 library From [this source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lz-string), but only allowed function compress & decompress.

It can't find CompressToUTF16 function as it's only way to compress data in local storage that working with firefox using angular 7.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to achieve what you want to do with this library.

If you look at the code from the Github repo you can see that only two methods are defined 
https://github.com/shail9689/ng-lz-string/blob/master/src/app/lz-string.ts.

```js
import * as JSLZString from 'lz-string';

export class LZString {
  compress(data: string) {
    // TODO: Code to compress
    return JSLZString.compress(data);
  }

  decompress(compressed: string) {
    // TODO: Code to decompress
    return JSLZString.decompress(compressed);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Example to achieve what you want to do in a service using the lz-string library:

**utf-16.service.ts**

```js
import * as JSLZString from 'lz-string';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Utf16Service {
  constructor() {}
  compress(data){
    return JSLZString.compressToUTF16(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to compress utf 16 with any library ?

Comment: Lz-string itself: https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/blob/feab58ba1de7ba4dd5f9c54c50ee9099e95887f7/libs/lz-string.js#L47

Comment: I updated my answer to provide you with an example.

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, could you validate it?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much.

Comment: Then, could you press the ✓ ? :)

Answer (score 0):

you must add `lz-string.js` Path to angular js file, then:

```
import * as JSLZString from 'lz-string';
```

Now you can use all `lz-string` library function .